# How does routing on wordpress work?

Tags: urls, routing

How does the core wp routing works? I am having a hard time understanding... In MVC, your url looks like mycontroller/myaction that maps to MyController->myaction()

In drupal, it's index.php?q=mycustomerpath/hello which can be mapped to any function you like that returns a content that is "themed" into your theme layout.

But in wp, i have no clue how things are done... it's ?p=1 then ?product=1 ... I have searched for documentation of the routing flow but can't find any (google just returns articles on custom routes).. i want to understand the fundamentals of the core routing first..

Comment: digging in the code, i see on each request it calls query_posts? why on earth does it needs to query posts each time? isn't there cases where you don't actually want to display posts??

Comment: Contents are saved as post in WP. So, when you need to show contents you need to query it

Comment: May I suggests that you read about "the loop" which is the concept that you need to understand to know how WordPress works. Essential "the loop" displays an array of posts which is the result of query_posts. For non-admin URL requests WP is designed to show only posts and it takes custom programming to show something besides a post. Admin URL requests are different and these do not use "the loop" and show non posts things.

Comment: ok but this approach is a bit weird and not very flexible tbh

Comment: say I want to display a contact form.. i need to put my html in  a page content type? I am still trying to find where to put the logic for the form submission... (in the theme page.php? very ugly approach)

Comment: You probably would not make a contact form store anything of the form itself in the database, you would code it as a plugin and have the logic for the form submission in the plugin. To output the special form code in a Page or Post, you define a shortcode.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're making a theme for yourself and don't want to bother with making a portable plugin, you can make a "Page Template" in your theme, with your code in it, then make a new Page and tell it to use that special template. Templates are PHP, they can do anything they like.

Answer (score 36):

In WordPress, URLs don't map to routes. They map to database queries.

When using WordPress in the "default" permalinks mode, you have a set of variables in the main URL query, like ?p=1 or ?page=234 and so forth. There's also ?s=search and many others.

If you use the "pretty" permalinks, then a big set of rules called the "rewrite rules" is created which directly maps various URL patterns onto this same set of URL parameters. So a URL like /2014/04/12/example would map to ?year=2014&month=04&day=12&postname=example or similar. So the following applies to these as well, after this mapping is done.

These variables are essentially controlling the main instance of the WP_Query class. The WP_Query class holds all the information that builds the database query to get the "posts" from the database. The various parameters passed into it control what kind of query it builds and what data it gets.

See, everything that can be displayed by WordPress is essentially a "post". A blog is a series of posts in reverse time-based order. A "page" is a static post with a defined name. A "custom post type" is exactly what it sounds like, a "post" with a custom type that you define. All main queries to display anything in WordPress are getting some subset of posts from the wp_posts table.

The WP_Query is what does that. And the parameters from the URL are sent directly into that main query and used there.

The theme then determines what template to use based on what the query comes back with. If you requested /category/example, then that becomes ?category_name=example which means that the main $wp_query->query_vars array will get that information, and the WP_Query will pull out the last X posts for the "example" category, and it will set its is_category flag to true.

The template-loader will run after this, see that is_category() returns true, and decide to pick the category template, so it will look for category-example.php and fall back to category.php and so on, according to the Template Hierarchy.

So, the question if you want to change how URLs work is simple: Do you want to change the URLs, or what they are mapped to? Because URLs are not mapped to functions, they're mapped to parameters that control the query. If you want have the URL adjust that main query, then it's a slightly different process than if you want a special URL to run some totally other special code.

And to answer your specific question in the comments: "isn't there cases where you don't actually want to display posts?" No, there is not. Everything is a post. All content is stored in posts. If you want to store content elsewhere and be different, then you can do that, but it's more difficult because, honestly, it's not usually necessary. If you have special content, make a custom post type, store your content as a post with that type, map a URL pattern to it. Easy.

Comment: I understand that everything should be represented in a post (via custom post types etc..) very similar to custom types in drupal 6... but does it affect performance having a single posts table to store every single content of the site? drupal 7 solved it by introducing entity type so that you don't have to create a custom type and store everything in the node table but in your own entity table which can still leverage from the drupal framework. I hope wordpress introduces such approach in the future. thx for the detailed explanation.

Comment: i guess if i want to map a url to a my own function/theme, wp router would help?

Comment: Adding a full routing system is not usually necessary. There are simpler ways. The basis of WordPress is to display user-generated content, which is all stored in the posts table. If you're wanting to display content which is not user generated, then you generally do it in the theme or in a plugin. There are hundreds (thousands) of action hooks and filters and other ways for code to override various parts of the process as the page is generated. And with things like shortcodes, inserting custom html into content is relatively easy.

Comment: how do I add custom html/php into a post type i created? without having the modify the theme's single.php or create a single-mycustompost.php (not a very portable approach)

Comment: Shortcodes. http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: @yeahman: I rather disagree with some of your judgements on wordpress - is a bit weird and not very flexible, very ugly approach, not a very portable approach. Although the builtin logic of wordpress would not be suitable for all kinds of website I think it much more flexible, portable and elegant than you can appreciate from working with it for only a little while. If you gain more experience with it I think you will find you can do much more than you seem to think. You really need to understand actions, filters, shortcodes, widgets, ... before you can pass a fair judgement.

Comment: I see from one of your previous questions that you are using the Pods plugin. This is a good example of the flexibility of WordPress. Pods does not use the builtin WordPress logic - query for posts and display posts using the loop. It replaces this with its own custom logic. It can do this because WordPress actions allows you to easily modify the default behavior of WordPress. And you can still use the all the capabilities of a very vast ecosystem built around WordPress.

Comment: i haven't used PODS yet.. reason i was considering a framework like PODS is out of the box, wp is not that great for web development. I understand wp was originally designed for blog use only but by version 3.0, i would think it would be more accessible for web development. Drupal is a good example of what i am talking... started up like a cms and evolved into a CMF (content management framework: probably the most powerful out there)

Comment: If your website requires custom programming on most of its pages then probably WordPress is not the right choice. I myself personally like the approach taken by concrete5 but find WordPress more viable because of its vast ecosystem - it probably has the largest collection plugins by far (of course some of those are just plain junk). Certainly, "the loop" logic shows its blogging origins but WordPress has evolved to be much more capable but it isn't a generic framework. If your requirements does not match "the loop" logic you are probably better off with something else.

Comment: @yeahman: So if you think Drupal is better for a specific case, then use Drupal. It's all free software. Use whatever fits your needs best. It won't hurt WordPress's feelings one bit. I mean, if you were making a wiki, I would not suggest WordPress for that either. :)

Comment: lol i am actually working on a project using wordpress so no drupal for me.. lol but there are actually some complex plugins built for wp like woocommerce, buddypress which are popular and does not have only content/posts pages... but digging in buddypress code, you can see they have done a lot of hacking to achieve this. Wp router plugin hopefully will solve my issue with the default routing of wp.

Comment: after more than 1 year working with wordpress now... I still is not convinced by it ... the framework is not elegant and quite ugly... It works as a simple blog but if you want to develop other types of websites.. it's kind of hacking wordpress to do something it was not meant to do.

Comment: and unfortunately I also experienced hacking on 3 wordpress sites already... so it is not very secured either...

Comment: Nearly all hacks are the result of you having an insecure server or plugin/theme code. WordPress's core is perfectly secure.

Comment: probably yes. But saying wordpress core is perfectly secure is a bit of an overstatement...Security patches and updates exist for a reason

Comment: Hi @Otto and others.

Now there is the WP REST API, I'm assuming there is a router of sorts? Would you be able to update your answer for say 4.7?

Comment: No. Why would you assume that things have changed? There is still no such thing. It's just an endpoint in the URL.

Comment: I have worked more on wordpress since my last comment and I have multiple sites got hacked; even sites with no additional third party plugins. Needed to create scripts to find the hacked files and clean them and install wordfence security to monitor them.

Comment: For those who wonder where the query is set, look for `wp();` in `wp-blog-header.php`