# What php gets called for home_url/somepage URL?

Tags: urls, archives

This is going to sound quite stupid for most experts but for a beginner it's not clear what .php code gets called when visiting a `home_url/year/month` URL.

For example, `domain.com/2018/05` shows all posts from that specific months.

Apparently, the same `.php` gets called for `domain.com/2018` too (except with more results).

I've looked left and right and read about `archives.php` (which I have) but it doesn't correspond with what actually gets rendered.

In some places I've read about `date.php` too, but I don't have such file.

Right now I'm specifically interested for archives, but with this question I'm looking for a general way to know exactly what php files are involved for a specific URL?

I am aware of [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence) but this talks about wordpress initialization. I'm interested in the first php file used for a given URL.

Comment: There's a lot of code that's run when you visit any page in WordPress. Do you just mean which *template* is used?

Comment: I'm not familiar with all the terms of wordpress. Perhaps yes, which template. I'd say what **file**

Comment: All URLs in WordPress go through /index.php, which loads the WordPress application (which comprises dozens of files) which then performs operations to determine what to display and does that by assembling multiple files from the theme according to the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). If you're trying to achieve something in particular it might help to know what so you can get a more specific answer.

Comment: well I have two instances of wordpress, in one, visiting `domain1.com/2018/05` leads to an entirely blank page (source code consists of empty head and body html) and in the other instance visiting `domain2.com/2018/05` leads to a page that shows all posts from that month. But I can't figure out, in neither instances, what `php` is used to display those posts. End goal is to fix instance #1

Comment: Well the issue with the first one just sounds like an error somewhere, which could be in pretty much any theme, plugin, or core file. My first suggestion would be to start deactivating plugins, or switching themes, until the issue goes away. The last thing you did before it fixes itself will tell you where the issue lies.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to give me these advices. I read about those debugging steps in some articles today (and that it is called white screen of death) but following those didn't help me. And the blank page is shown only for those archive pages. I wanted to know how apache served that blank page and exactly what file was called initially. For example, in django I would go to the urls.py file which shows me all the routes and interpret the code myself. Even with debug true I still see only a blank page. So I thought maybe there is a way to see the routes and go from there

Comment: WordPress's doesn't really use 'routes'. See [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141072/how-does-routing-on-wordpress-work) question and answer for a rough overview of how URLs are parsed in WordPress.

Comment: Hmm this is a duplicate of that question. Thank you!

Comment: Install the Query Monitor plugin - that will tell you which template file is being used.

Comment: @JacobPeattie with the help of the link you provided I managed to find out that the archives.php was buggy. I created one myself that was used with priority and now the issue is gone. Many thanks for the help! I wish I could give you a rep bounty but it can't be done on comments

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I posted elsewhere here:

WordPress is not HTML. It's PHP-based templates that build the HTML pages.

You need more than just a quick answer. You need to learn about the entire process WordPress uses to build pages.

Perhaps one place is to start here to figure out how WP works: https://codex.wordpress.org/New_To_WordPress_-_Where_to_Start . And if you are not comfortable with PHP, then you need to get some basics about how it works so you will understand the code behind the WP templates. Perhaps start here to learn about PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/pHP/default.asp .

This is not going to be a quick process. It will take some time and effort on your part. But you might have fun doing it.

Comment: Weird how WP is advertised at being so quick to use yet when it comes to doing just a little more you need to know everything

Comment: If you want to change how your site works with content, then you need to grok how WP works, and how it uses templates to get data and format it for viewing; see my link. Templates are the 'PHP file used for a page'. The templates use built-in WP functions -WP is the 'engine', and template files are the 'content formatters' that use data provided by the engine. The 'engine' does all the work involved in getting/storing data. Themes: collection of templates and CSS that format the output to HTML for the visitor. Plugins:extensions to the engine that add capability. Read the links to understand.