# Sequence of finding a website when they are running Wordpress

Tags: server

So, as I understood it. The browser asks for a website, say, myWebsite.com.
After churning around the internet where that site is reached and the request is passed to the server software, I’m assuming Apache (doesn’t matter). Apache then finds the file MyWebsite.com/index and sends it back to the browser.

But if MyWebsite.com is running Wordpress how does it know that and launch Wordpress rather than looking for my “index” file?

Comment: Still finds index.php that launches WordPress.  The index.php file from WordPress kicks off the whole process.

Comment: There are lots of ways to answer this question, but it's been answered many times.. search for wordpress routing.. or go higher and try to understand how that "churning" works thanks to DNS and other magical stuff..  good info on the WP part here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141072/how-does-routing-on-wordpress-work/141087#141087